# If my index is growing further, is there a way to auto partition the index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In Elasticsearch, my index size has grown rapidly, thereby delaying the replication. Is there a way to auto partition the index in elasticsearch. I know a way to use create a new index with alias name shared programmatically. Wondering if the same can be handled at admin level.

For ex:

index_main has grown to an extent where the replication is causing a problem, I need to automatically create dynamic indexes say index_022019, index_032019 etc.

Comment: Did you try using shards?

Comment: Could you elaborate the best way of sharding?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the number of shards to split your content and parallelize operations.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#create-index-settings) is the link to the official documentation to create shards.